# Uniform distribution train question

Tags: probability

You enter a metro station in a big hurry, and decide to take the first train that arrives.

There are two lines running through this station: one runs every five minutes (line A), the other every three (line B). To be precise, suppose the next arrival of the A train is uniformly distributed on the interval [0, 5], and similarly for the B train on [0, 3]. The two arrivals are independent.

The trains run like clockwork: there's no uncertainty other than the next arrival time. For example, given that the next B train arrives at time 0.87, you can be absolutely certain that there will be another at time 3.87.

How many minutes will you wait on average until you get on a train?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort.

Answer (score 1):

As Karn said, Using $P(T>t)=P(A>t,B>t)=P(A>t)\times P(B>t)$, we get $P(T>t)=\frac{(5-t)\times(3-t)}{15}$. Hence we can find $P(T<=t)$ and thus the distribution of T. We can then easily calculate the expected value of T which comes to be $\frac{6}{5}$.

Answer (score 1):

**Method 1**:

If Z = min(X,Y)

p(Z>z) = p(X>z and Y>z) = p(X>z). p(Y>z) Independent = 1/15. (5-z)(3-z) . (0

dF= d(1-p(Z>z)) = -1/15.(2z-8)dz

E[z] = int [z. dF] = -1/15.(2z3/3-8z2/2) =1.2 min, for z=3

**Method 2:**

Given that both trains arrive in the first three minutes, the expected value of the minimum is 1/3 of the total possible time, I.e. 1 minute. If X arrives in the last 2 minutes, the expected value of the min is simply the expected value of Y, which is 1.5. the probability of the first scenario is 3/5 and the second is 2/5, so using conditional expectation we get:

E = 3/5*1 + 2/5 *(1.5) = 6/5

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Consider the waiting time $T$ such that
$$T=\min\{A,B\}$$

So$$P(T>t)=P(A>t,B>t)=P(A>t)\cdot P(B>t)$$
by independence.